# How to retrieve image using url path saved in database using c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I need to retrieve images from a server using url path. I'm working in a console application that generates pdf reports, i'm using entity models to retrieve data from DB and using html to create the reports.

I though that by getting the urlpath from server and putting it inside **ex:**

```
string html = "<img src='" + inspector_Signature + "'>";
```

would work, it just comes out blank.

This is my query:

```
using (var context = new dbName_pdf.dbName_dbEntities())
        {
            var db_data= (from lo in context.tbl_loans
                         join doc in context.tbl_docinfo on lo.idDocInfo equals doc.idDocInfo
                         join insp in context.tbl_inspections on lo.idLoan equals insp.idLoan
                         join p1 in context.tbl_pir01 on lo.idLoan equals p1.idLoan
                         join pho in context.tbl_photos on lo.idLoan equals pho.idLoan
                         join me in context.tbl_members on insp.idMember equals me.id
                         join sig in context.tbl_inspector_signature on me.id equals sig.idMember
                         join p2 in context.tbl_pir02 on lo.idLoan equals p2.idLoan
                         join cm in context.tbl_comments_inspections on lo.idLoan equals cm.idLoan
                         where insp.StatusInspections == 3 && lo.idLoan == 5
                         orderby cm.CommentDateCreated descending
                         select new
                         {
                             Loan = lo,
                             DocInfo = doc,
                             Inspection = insp,
                             pir1 = p1,
                             pir2 = p2,
                             photos = pho,
                             members = me,
                             signature = sig,
                             inspection_comments = cm
                         });
```

The string i'm using to store the image:

```
string inspector_Signature = db_data.First().signature.locationSign;
```

Note: I searched for a solution but all the questions i found dealt with MVC/ASP.net which didn't applied to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future folk, this is the answer.

I only needed to add the full url path.

```
string inspector_Signature = "http://www.webpage.com/" + db_data.First().signature.locationSign;
```

The image now renders when i add it to my html string:

```
string html = "<img src='" + inspector_Signature + "' width='180' height='50'>";
```